# #region in axml file for xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android

hello I am trying to make my code in the axml file more readable I have a lot of switches in my program and I want to shrink this part of the code. I read something about it and I found

```
<!--#region Name-->
   My Code
<!--#endregion-->
```

But it is referred as a normal comment. Could you help me out? I am using Visual Studio 2017 in case it is important to mention.

Answer (score 0):

> # region in axml file for xamarin.android

If you want to make the `.axml` file more readable, you could click the indent button: [Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FayXT.png).

---

Or you could use the `<include/>` tag  embed another layout inside the current layout to make it more readable. For example, create a `titlebar.axml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/titlebar_bg"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" >

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/gafricalogo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Use it in another layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"
          android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

## Update:

I think the [XAML Regions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacobJohnston.XAMLRegions) is what you are looking in your `.axml` file.

## Update 2:

Install this plugin for your Visual Studio, close all your Visual Studio windows and reopen the VS. Then, you could the the `#Region` function for your

```
<!-- Region (Any Text You Want) --> 
 Your Code 
<!-- EndRegion -->
```

Comment: My point is that I have 32 switches in my code. I find it stupid to click on the button you are talking about for everyone of them. I wanted to specify an area that can be collapsed and hidden when I want so I can hide all of them at once.

Comment: Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @GeorgiYakov, got it, I have updated my answer, please check it. It works fine on my side.

Comment: @GeorgiYakov, have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I saw it but maybe I'm too stupid and it didn't work :)

Comment: @GeorgiYakov, I tested on my side and it works fine. :)